Where to destroy TextEditingController when passing as a function parameter?
There are documentation on how to properly destroy TextEditingController, but these documentation don't help my case. I have duplicate codes in my project, so I was thinking to minimize the code by creating a function which needs to be of the following signature:
Widget displayMyWidgets(String label, TextEditingController _controller) {
  return Container(
    // codes to display widget(s) here.
  );
}

I've also read that you can not leave streams, and TextEditingController un-disposed, as that causes memory leaks, and that they are still usable if we don't dispose them. (These must be correct?)
So, if I use the above function in my project where am I supposed to destroy the _controller? Or will the garbage collector work in this case when the _controller is local to the function? (Please point to the resources if possible.) In above, for sure, I won't be able to call .dispose() after the return function!
In my Container mainly I use TextField in readonly mode to display dynamic text so I don't think I could write any code in its onChanged or somewhere else?

Don't pass TextEditingController in the function parameter. You can pass String in parameter and while passing those data to function you can user controller.text . Also if you need to use TextEditingController and a function is created in UI then you can directly use in function don't need to pass.

Create it in a Widget: Usually, you'll create the TextEditingController within a StatefulWidget.
Dispose in Widget's dispose() Method: Dispose of the TextEditingController in the StatefulWidget's dispose() method to release its resources.
Don't Dispose in the Function: Avoid disposing it within the function that receives it. Instead, let the widget owning the controller handle its disposal.
